# Need to execute . ./setantenv.sh to set ant environment variable for SAP commerce in shell script

Tags: bash, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using below shell script code to set ant env for commerce package. But it is not setting the variable.

code 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
./usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads/commerce/hybris/bin/platform/setantenv.sh >>/usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads/logsetantenv.txt
```

Does any one have an idea about it?

Comment: What is there inside the setantenv.sh ? What are the values that you are trying to append to the txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute a separate process to set a variable in the current one (unless you are writing a debugger, and you don't want to go there).

To set a variable in the *current* process then you need to execute the script using the `source` command, often using `.` command instead as an alternative name.

It appears to me that you are just missing a space after the leading dot (it is unlikely that you have that directory tree in your current directory):

```
. /usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads/commerce/hybris/bin/platform/setantenv.sh >>/usr/sap/Silentinstall/commercedownloads/logsetantenv.txt
```